# There are 14 identical objects that will be placed into 3 boxes. In how many ways can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics

For this combination problem, I used the formula for combination (n + k - 1) choose (k - 1) to get the answer of (14 choose 2).

Is this correct? If not, can someone explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to place $n$ identical objects into $k$ distinguishable boxes, where some boxes may be empty, is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, or equivalently $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$. The argument that shows this uses the technique of Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia).

In our case, $n=14$ and $k=3$, so the number of ways is $\binom{16}{2}$.